# How to rank values towards 0 as the lowest in R?

Tags: r, ranking

I have a vector that contains both negative and positive values. I want to rank them in such a way that values close to 0 gets 1st rank and the values farthest from 0 irrespective of sign should get the highest rank. Here is one example data with ranks

```
Value           Rank
0.817305499     8
0.22799983      5
-0.015915982    1
0.271941164     6
0.851973536     9
-0.679487051    7
0.09247952      2
-1.047086596    10
-0.174033279    3
0.189823311     4
```

How can I achieve this in R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `order` by `abs`

```
> with(df,df[order(abs(Value)), ])
         Value Rank
3  -0.01591598    1
7   0.09247952    2
9  -0.17403328    3
10  0.18982331    4
2   0.22799983    5
4   0.27194116    6
6  -0.67948705    7
1   0.81730550    8
5   0.85197354    9
8  -1.04708660   10
```

or `rank` if you just want to create a new column

```
> transform(df, Rank2 = rank(abs(Value)))
         Value Rank Rank2
1   0.81730550    8     8
2   0.22799983    5     5
3  -0.01591598    1     1
4   0.27194116    6     6
5   0.85197354    9     9
6  -0.67948705    7     7
7   0.09247952    2     2
8  -1.04708660   10    10
9  -0.17403328    3     3
10  0.18982331    4     4
```

Comment: I want only the rank column as output. How can it be done?

Comment: @UseR10085 then you use `rank(abs(df$Value))` for you dataframe `df`